# Access AWS Elasticache from GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, vpn, amazon-elasticache

My use case is I have an elasticache cluster setup in AWS and I want to access it from GCP.
I tried setting up a tunnel between AWS and GCP and tried redis benchmarking but this adds up a lot of latency. I also tried setting up two S2S VPN tunnels between AWS & GCP so that way I will have around `3.x Gbits/sec` bandwidth for the tunnel but still, the benchmarking results are the same.

Is there any other/better way to access AWS Elasticache from GCP without any added latency?

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the region both of them are located in. Try to select regions which are closer to each other.

Comment: I tried doing that but the benchmarking numbers are still the same.

Comment: if it was same cloud provider across different regions there are possible solutions.. But as this is different cloud provider ; then traffic has to go via internet only. If it is really critical; you could explore putting CDN in between but I don't think network is the issue here because as u mentioned u tried proximity locations still that did not help.